# C# Constructor as Func (without reflection)

Tags: c#, reflection, function-pointers, func

I have a set of configuration objects whose constructors all take the same parameters. Is it possible to assign a constructor to a Func, or something similar, so that the constructor can be invoked in a generic way?

For example:

```
public class FooConfig : ConfigBase {
    public FooConfig(int a) { ... }
}

public class BarConfig : ConfigBase {
    public BarConfig(int a) { ... }
}
```

In calling code:

```
Func<int, ConfigBase> fooConfigCtr = FooConfig.FooConfig; // Obviously this doesn't work
FooConfig fooConfig = (FooConfig) fooConfigCtr(12345);
```

The calling code example is not to show the actual use, but just to show why I am having difficulty using Func for this case.

A workaround I have found is to provide a static Factory method on each class with the same signature, and have that call a private constructor. However it is slightly non-optimal.

Comment: out of pure curiosity, what's wrong with using the conventional constructor itself?

Comment: In the calling code we want to call the constructor in a generic way, which requires assigning a constructor to a Func or a factory method to a Func.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to provide a static factory method. It may not be exactly what you want, but you could use a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), like this:

```
Func<int, ConfigBase> fooConfigCtr = n => new FooConfig(n);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to avoid the extra function/lambda

Comment: @user3339997 You can use a lambda expression, reflection, or factory method. Unfortunately, those are really your only options with C#, since you can't bind a delegate directly to a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Func<int, ConfigBase> fooConfigCtr = a => new FooConfig(a);
    FooConfig fooConfig = (FooConfig)fooConfigCtr(12345);
```

Without lambda expression you can try using the Activator.

```
    Type typeOfYourClass = typeof (FooConfig);
    FooConfig fooConfig = (FooConfig)Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfYourClass, 12345);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to avoid the extra function/lambda

Answer (score 0):

If you need a more dynamic way you can do it like this:

```
Func<int,ConfigBase> GetFactoryFunction(Type t)
{
    if(t == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("t");
    if(!typeof(ConfigBase).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException();

    return i => (ConfigBase)Activator.CreateInstance(t,i);
}
```

Or even generic:

```
Func<int,TDerived> GetFactoryFunction<TDerived>() where TDerived : ConfigBase
{
    return i => (TDerived)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TDerived),i);
}
```

Comment: Activator is reflection, is it not?